# Google Analytics: How to track pages in a single page application?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-analytics, single-page-application

Currently in my [website](http://derek1906.site50.net/), I used HTML5's [`pushState()`](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) and `popState` in links to increase the speed. However, this doesn't really change the *real* URL and it looks like it will affect and mess up the [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/)'s code. (doesn't show a url change) Is there a possible solution for this? Thanks,

Comment: [Event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html).

Comment: Never mind, found [this](http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics).

Comment: It does change the real URL. In browsers that support the History API, pushState should change the URL in the address bar and in the Location objection. What it doesn't do is change the loaded resource. That is up to you, and it's the whole point of the History API.

Comment: @gWiz - What I meant was that it is not requesting the new page like normal and the scripts didn't got reloaded.

Comment: This article has the most decent explanation https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/03/30/single-page-applications-google-analytics/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are using the newer `analytics.js` API, [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) requires the following code to trigger the event:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/some-page');
```

If you are using the older `ga.js` API, [David Walsh suggests](http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics) AJAX websites to use the `_gaq.push` method:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/some-page']);
```

Comment: You still might want to look into event tracking, it's good for "ajaxy" apps. You can track a lot more than page views.

Comment: so if you only change the url using pushState() and after that call _gaq.push(['_trackPageview') it won't work in GA?

Comment: @VinnyG: More than a year later, with the new analytics.js sdk -- it will just work. More details in my answer.

Comment: Even though I've upvoted this answer, I believe it's a bit out of date and the correct answer is the one written by @Nicolo.  At present days documentation suggests to use `set` command first and then use `send`, e.g. `ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html'); ga('send', 'pageview');`.

Answer (score 25):

I know it's old question but since this question is first result in Google about tracking pushState() in Google Analytics and all answers are wrong I decided to answer it.

In other answers they mentioned to use directly ga('send' ..... ) but this is wrong way to do it.

First you have to 'set' parameters and then use 'send' to track it.

If you want to update only url, use following code

```js
// set new url 
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page');

// send it for tracking
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

If you want to update url and title, add title parameter to it

```js
// set new url and title
ga('set', {
  page: '/new-page',
  title: 'New Page'
});

// send it for tracking
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Source [Single Page Application Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications?hl=en)

Comment: +1 for including source reference. It may be a bit harsh to say `ga('send', 'page', '/new-page');` is _wrong_. The source suggests `'send'` this but then says you should use `'set'` "if you send other hits (e.g. events or social hits)".

Comment: This must be an accepted answer (see my earlier comment) until current one is not up to date

Answer (score 11):

## February 2018 Update - Global Site Tag (gtag.js)

Google Analytics has a new tracking code snippet, so the other answers might not work for gtag.

This is the default tracking code. It only runs once even though we try to run it each URL changes.

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
```

But with a `page_path` parameter we can make GA run manually.

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': '/new-page.html'});
```

And we can make something like this.

```
var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
var pathname = window.location.href.substr(origin.length);
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': pathname});
```

[Single page application tracking with gtag.js (Google documentation)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications)

Answer (score 9):

## Recent answer (2017)

You can now use **Google's [`autotrack.js`](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack)**, a script that enhances `analytics.js`.

It includes a plugin that **automatically tracks URL changes** for single page applications.

You just need to include the script and the following line in your html:

```
ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker');
```

Comment: I believe that this won't help in the scenario where you want to track page fragments aka hash aka everything after #.

Answer (score 8):

## 2020 Update

If you are using `Google Analytics 4` you don't need to push the event anymore IF you enabled the **Page views** option in the **Enhanced measurement** feature in **Data Streams** menu.

[image: Enhanced measurement]

Comment: In that screen go to Settings > Uncheck "Page changes based on browser history events" and then push pageviews using gtag('event', 'page_view', {page_location: 'your URL', page_title: 'your title'});

Comment: From the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/views?client_type=gtag#measure_virtual_pageviews): "To measure virtual pageviews, **either** rely on enhanced measurement, which sends a pageview when the browser history state changes, **or** manually send the page_view event." In other words, you don't need to uncheck the "Page changes based on browser history events" option as this feature tracks page views automatically for `History API` and `document.title` changes.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, here in September 2013,

  **Google Analytics has a new JavaScript API.**

After you've included Google's new "*analytics.js*" asynchronous snippet, use the *send pageview command* to track pages:

`ga('send','pageview');`

After your pushState madness, use this *send pageview command* to track your asynchronous navigation. According to [**Google's Documentation on Page Tracking with Analytics.js**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages), ***the send pageview command will magically read and track the new location given by pushState,*** as it will, in the moment the *send pageview command* is called, use the following values by default (though you can specify them):

```
var locationToTrack = window.location.protocol+'//'
  +window.location.hostname 
  +window.location.pathname 
  +window.location.search;

var titleToTrack = document.title;

var pathToTrack = location.pathname+location.search;
```

*Note, Google's standard analytics snippet includes an initial send pageview command.*

### Update:

I've implemented Google Analytics tracking on my website in the way above that I described -- however, it does not seem to be successfully tracking any of the pushState page views.

I'm going to try specifying the location, title, and page name explicitly on the send pageview command, and see if GA tracks properly.

I'll post back with the results, unless I forget.

Comment: Nevermind. Tested myself and ga('send','pageview') after history navigation does **not** send the updated URL.

Comment: @gWiz: I believe I never got the pageview tracking to work, even though I used Google Analytics Debugger (a browser extension) to confirm that my implementation was sending the pageview hit correctly to google.. that were never received.

I ended up being extremely frustrated. So I quit and left Google Analytics. Now I just use awstats from cPanel :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ga('send', 'pageview')` was not registering a pageview on GA.

The way that worked for me is:

```js
window.ga.getAll()[0].set('page', location);
window.ga.getAll()[0].send('pageview');
```

I can use it after changing the url with `history.pushState`.

Answer (score -1):

I also had problems with ga('send','pageview');, after using history.pushState.

The workaround was simply make the URL explicit.
ga('send','pageview','/my-url')

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the main question, perhaps it is better suited as a comment to ChaseMoskal's answer.